# selecting radio options doesnt change checked attribute

Tags: javascript

I am generating an HTML form with some radio buttons and checkboxes. the generated code for the radio buttons for instance are like these:

```
<input id="101_2" type="radio" name="101" value="2" >
<input id="101_3" type="radio" name="101" value="3" checked="true">
```

Using JavaScript I can make a for cycle to see what radio is checked using the check attribute.
The problem is that if I manually click in another radio option (from the same group as in the example), visually in the HTML I can see that another radio is selected, but the JavaScript is still saying that the input 101_3 is the selected radio option. If I look at the HTML using firebug I can see that the new selected option is indeed not selected (doesn't have the checked attribute)... despite I have selected manually.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: please post your HTML and Javascript code to better suggest you....

Comment: *"Any ideas on this?"* Your JavaScript code might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Fist and formost when naming your radio buttons or any type of DOM input element never start the name of an input element with a number, always start the name of your input element with a letter.

For your posted code you would name your radios in similar fashion, one01 or x101 or o101,ect...

Do the same thing with your ids' of any DOM element. Never start an id of a DOM element with a number.

--HTML

```
<input id="x101_2" type="radio" name="x101" value="2">
<input id="x101_3" type="radio" name="x101" value="3" checked="checked">
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="WhatsChecked()">Whats Checked?</button>
```

--JavaScript

```
function WhatsChecked() {
 var radCk = document.body.querySelectorAll('input[name="x101"]:checked')[0];
 alert(radCk.id);
 };
```

--Fiddler

[fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/EjLwv/2/)

Comment: Why should the OP not use a name that starts with a number? It's valid in HTML4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT . *"Do the same thing with your ids' of any DOM element"* HTML5 allows to use any characters as IDs and most browser supported this for a long while.

Comment: It is a bad practice.

Comment: If a web designer was a little advanced and was styling his or her elements that some of them started with a number then they could do [id='101'], but that's limiting your options. The styling would still be the same but you would only have one option.

Comment: I've had issues in the past when using CSS when styling DOM elements that start with a number. Maybe I'm missing something but if I've run into issues when attempting to style an element like so, .101{} or #101{}, What I'm getting at if a developer gets in the habit of using a number for ids' and names' then starts styling with CSS he or she could have issues, and if the case is that the website in question has a lot of work already done then the styling was to begin, this could be an issue. Regardless what w3.org says, I've actually had issues in the past.